# Is there a Transaction Log for what was changed when you run an Update via Tortoise?

Tags: windows-7, svn, tortoise-svn

A coworker was remoting into my PC and ran an Update on a folder and closed the window before I could look over the changes.

I know you can just Right Click and go to `Show Log` but that's a list of recent commits. I had some un-committed changes to a utility in the folder and I'd swear it said `Reverted` while the Update was running, because I made the changes yesterday and now they've been undone.

So, simply put, I'm trying to find a log that'll show me what files were modified in the Update that was just run. I know Update isn't *supposed* to undo any uncomitted changes, but I can't fathom what happened since 5PM yesterday and 2PM today to some local files that I haven't touched today.